# Site going low in google page search

Tags: seo, google-search, search-results, ranking

my site was ranking almost around 1-2 link 1 month ago for major of the post search terms like "alan walker - Faded Mp3" but now when i search for my latest post or my old post the site is not even showing in the google search result.

Answer (score 2):

There are many reasons as to why this is happening. Not knowing the specifics I will create a basic checklist of the things you should start looking at:

- Website has been blocked accidentally via robots.txt.
- You have been penalised. Look for any warning messages in Search Console.
- Search for your site in Google using the operator site:example.com to check if your website has been de-indexeed, if not
- Review how Google sees your website by looking at the homepage cache.
- Your website has been hacked.
- Your website is being attacked with negative SEO (Some people believe this is not a real issue).
- The content of your page has change (hacked again?)
- The website has been redesigned
- The WebSite has been migrated into another server or platform.
- The website or a particular page is currently in violation of [google guidelines](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35769?hl=en).
- You have accidentally applied a canonical tag pointing to another site.
- There is a bad hreflang implementation
- The website is not crawlable for any other particular reason, like Ajax generated content or bad JavaScript code.
- Google has updated their index and new players had come to play.

Comment: THanks so much for the response..  But i checked all of the points but there is no problem like that..  Site -  mp3chest.com. PLEASE HELP

Comment: @Tanish you need to give it sometime before Google index your new posts/pages, and even longer to start ranking. Be patience.